# Assigning Default Value Using ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, modelbuilder, error-999999, default-value

Task: add several new fields to a feature class table and assign a default value to one of the fields.

Software/Environment: Using ArcMap 10.2 (Advanced License) and Python 2.7. Data is stored in file geodatabase in WGS_84 projection.

I used ModelBuilder to string the add field tools together and generate each new field. The last step in the model is to assign a default value based on a variable input. My model is shown below:

[image]

The desired output is shown below. This screen shot is from a finished edit, where I used the field calculator within the table to set the values after the tool had run.
[image]

The model fails on adding the default value. The error log is below:

```
Executing: BV-IKE-Processing test2 test2
Start Time: Wed Apr 15 09:32:33 2015
Executing (Add BV_PoleID): AddField test2 BV_PoleID TEXT # # 13 # NULLABLE NON_REQUIRED #
Start Time: Wed Apr 15 09:32:33 2015
Adding BV_PoleID to test2...
Succeeded at Wed Apr 15 09:32:33 2015 (Elapsed Time: 0.08 seconds)
Executing (Add X_Long): AddField test2 X_Long DOUBLE # # # # NULLABLE NON_REQUIRED #
Start Time: Wed Apr 15 09:32:33 2015
Adding X_Long to test2...
Succeeded at Wed Apr 15 09:32:33 2015 (Elapsed Time: 0.09 seconds)
Executing (Add Y_Lat): AddField test2 Y_Lat DOUBLE # # # # NULLABLE NON_REQUIRED #
Start Time: Wed Apr 15 09:32:33 2015
Adding Y_Lat to test2...
Succeeded at Wed Apr 15 09:32:34 2015 (Elapsed Time: 0.07 seconds)
Executing (Add Z_Alt): AddField test2 Z_Alt SHORT # # # # NULLABLE NON_REQUIRED #
Start Time: Wed Apr 15 09:32:34 2015
Adding Z_Alt to test2...
Succeeded at Wed Apr 15 09:32:34 2015 (Elapsed Time: 0.09 seconds)
Executing (Add Data_Pkg): AddField test2 Data_Pkg TEXT # # # # NULLABLE NON_REQUIRED #
Start Time: Wed Apr 15 09:32:34 2015
Adding Data_Pkg to test2...
Succeeded at Wed Apr 15 09:32:34 2015 (Elapsed Time: 0.09 seconds)
Executing (Add Status): AddField test2 Status TEXT # # # # NULLABLE NON_REQUIRED #
Start Time: Wed Apr 15 09:32:34 2015
Adding Status to test2...
Succeeded at Wed Apr 15 09:32:34 2015 (Elapsed Time: 0.06 seconds)
Executing (Assign Data_Pkg): AssignDefaultToField test2 Data_Pkg test2 #
Start Time: Wed Apr 15 09:32:34 2015
ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
Failed to execute (Assign Data_Pkg).
Failed at Wed Apr 15 09:32:34 2015 (Elapsed Time: 0.02 seconds)
Failed to execute (BV-IKE-Processing).
Failed at Wed Apr 15 09:32:34 2015 (Elapsed Time: 0.64 seconds)
```

I converted the model to a python script in case it will help. The python version is here:

```
    # Import arcpy module
import arcpy

# Script arguments
Input_Table = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)

Data_Pkg_Name = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

# Local variables:
Output_Feature_Class = Input_Table
Output_Feature_Class__2_ = Output_Feature_Class
Output_Feature_Class__3_ = Output_Feature_Class__2_
Output_Feature_Class__4_ = Output_Feature_Class__3_
Output_Feature_Class__5_ = Output_Feature_Class__4_
Output_Feature_Class__6_ = Output_Feature_Class__5_
Output_Table = Output_Feature_Class__6_

# Process: Add BV_PoleID
arcpy.AddField_management(Input_Table, "BV_PoleID", "TEXT", "", "", "13", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")

# Process: Add X_Long
arcpy.AddField_management(Output_Feature_Class, "X_Long", "DOUBLE", "", "", "", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")

# Process: Add Y_Lat
arcpy.AddField_management(Output_Feature_Class__2_, "Y_Lat", "DOUBLE", "", "", "", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")

# Process: Add Z_Alt
arcpy.AddField_management(Output_Feature_Class__3_, "Z_Alt", "SHORT", "", "", "", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")

# Process: Add Data_Pkg
arcpy.AddField_management(Output_Feature_Class__4_, "Data_Pkg", "TEXT", "", "", "25", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")

# Process: Add Status
arcpy.AddField_management(Output_Feature_Class__5_, "Status", "TEXT", "", "", "50", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")

# Process: Assign Data_Pkg
arcpy.AssignDefaultToField_management(Output_Feature_Class__6_, "Data_Pkg", Data_Pkg_Name, "")
```

Disclaimers: I'm a noob when it comes to coding/scripting/model builder. This is intended to be a time saver for me and possibly be extended by some more complex coding (creating an iterator to generate the BV_PoleID, etc).

---

I edited the tool to include text lengths for the Data_Pkg and Status fields. The tool still failed to assign the default value and returned the same error message.

Comment: Decided to run Assign Default Value to Field straight from ArcToolbox with the same parameters as my model. The tool ran successfully, but didn't assign the values.

Comment: Note that assign default value, only assigns a default value to the field; thus any NEW row will get the value, However it doesn't alter the rows which are already there. To do the latter you should use calculate field with a python expression as: `'%Value%'`

Answer (score 1):

Attached below is a modification of your code that works.

Shortly, the problem was the use of outputs names, as follows:

```
# Local variables:
Output_Feature_Class = Input_Table
Output_Feature_Class__2_ = Output_Feature_Class
Output_Feature_Class__3_ = Output_Feature_Class__2_
Output_Feature_Class__4_ = Output_Feature_Class__3_
Output_Feature_Class__5_ = Output_Feature_Class__4_
Output_Feature_Class__6_ = Output_Feature_Class__5_
Output_Table = Output_Feature_Class__6_
```

Namely, python or model builder do not handle underlines well (when it ends a variable name). Fixing it is easy if you follow those rules:

1. In model builder, use the rename option to rename your outputs and prevent using spaces, underlines, dash, Brackets, or any other sign which is not a letter or a number.
2. If in arcpy, do the same, without renaming - just give proper names. See the modified code below:

   ```
     # Import arcpy module
     import arcpy

     # Script arguments
     Input_Table = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
     Data_Pkg_Name = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

     # Local variables:
     Output1 = Input_Table
     Output2 = Output1
     Output3= Output2
     Output4 = Output3
     Output5 = Output4
     Output6= Output5
     Output_Table = Output6

     # Process: Add BV_PoleID
     arcpy.AddField_management(Input_Table, "BV_PoleID", "TEXT", "", "", "13", "",    "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")

     # Process: Add X_Long
      arcpy.AddField_management(Output1, "X_Long", "DOUBLE", "", "", "", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")

     # Process: Add Y_Lat
     arcpy.AddField_management(Output2, "Y_Lat", "DOUBLE", "", "", "", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")

     # Process: Add Z_Alt
     arcpy.AddField_management(Output3, "Z_Alt", "SHORT", "", "", "", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")

     # Process: Add Data_Pkg
     arcpy.AddField_management(Output4, "Data_Pkg", "TEXT", "", "", "25", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")

     # Process: Add Status
     arcpy.AddField_management(Output5, "Status", "TEXT", "", "", "50", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")

     # Process: Assign Data_Pkg
     arcpy.AssignDefaultToField_management(Output6, "Data_Pkg", Data_Pkg_Name, "")
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your python version, it appears you are not setting the length of the text fields when you add them, you must do this, it is not optional for a text field. This would explain why the assign default would fail.

Comment: My question was edited to include your answer. The tool still failed. Thank you for the help.

Comment: That should read my *script. Thanks for your help in making my code cleaner.